# How to get money in Fire Emblem Thracia 776

Tags: fire-emblem-thracia-776

I've just started playing Thracia and have gotten through a few levels, up to about Mount Violdrake. I've seen shops since lvl 1, but i never had money for them, and i never received money at the start, like other games. is there a pile of Money later on, or is there another way i'm supposed to get money?                                 Btw, I've mostly been playing the GBA FE Games, occasionally playing something like Genealogy every once in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this FAQ on GameFaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/snes/577344-fire-emblem-thracia-776/faqs/57162):

> Capturing is your primary source of equipment and items, as there is
>   virtually no way to make Gold aside from capturing, and Weapons cost a lot.

So unlike other Fire Emblem games, you need to be conscious about money, since you won't just receive or find much of it. It's probably one of the many reasons why Thracia 776 is considered to be the hardest Fire Emblem game to date.

Comment: so i get money from capturing enemies and taking and selling their weapons? wish i'd known that sooner...